# why yandex can not get satellite map by tiles api and use different pro4j

Tags: dictionary, yandex, wgs84

I want to ues yandex map in my app, and I has seen tiles api doc,but the tiles api can only get vector sytle map, iwant to use satellite by tiles api,how to solve this problem.

iwant to use satellite by tiles api,how to solve this problem.